# Image Localization

Tags: wpf, windows, localization

I'm building a WPF app that has to have two different logos - one for when the device is in english, and one for the rest of the cases.

I have place the english logo in the Assets/en folder, and the other logo directly in the Assets folder.

My problem is that whatever language I choose, the app shows the english logo.

An interesting note is that I have different strings for several languages of the app, and those work as they are supposed to, only the images are the problem here.

Comment: show your code of XAML and where you change source of an `Image`

Comment: Well i don't change the source of the image, I've read that the structure of the folders should be enought, just like in Android. This is my XAML code: `<Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Assets/logo.png" ` />

Comment: if you do not change the source of image, then there is no chance to change `Image`

Comment: If i create a file called `logo.lang-de.png`, then the app will use that one for my app, so it must work without changing the code. But i don't want to create a file for all the languages that my app will be available in, I want it to use the default `logo.png`, and only change it for english.

Comment: it is hard to help you without any code and clarifying information what you've tried to do it.

Comment: I have no code for this issue. I have a an image in the Assets folder, and one in Assets/en. No matter what language i use for the app, the image under Assets/en is used. I have tried setting `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` to another language, and changing the `CultureInfo`, but nothing helped.

Comment: man, C# does not know what a folder should be chosen `Assets/en`  or just `Assets ` without instructions(code)